# How to get the value of a field in php form on the same page

Tags: php

I am designing a web page. I want to have the options(of another drop-down list on same page) based on the selection made by the user.
I am providing a drop-down list to the user called Application. Depending on the Application, I want to query sql and want to show only the options that are valid for selected Application in another drop-down list.
I want  to get the value of Application on the same page (one that user has selected) and by getting that value will query the sql accordingly.

Comment: simple you just print those with print_r($_POST);

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), please.

Comment: @ John Conde: Excellent link

Answer (score 1):

Once the page is loaded, the PHP cannot do anything more.

You cannot use PHP based on user interaction.

The only way to do so is through javascript.
Using ajax, you can retrieve data from a certain URL on your javascript.

A procedure would be like this:

1. User selects something
2. The javascript(ajax) loads a URL
3. In that URL, use your PHP to fetch a certain query
4. The result would be sent to javascript, so display the result.

Here's a good page explaining ajax:

http://wabism.com/ajax-tutorial-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

you have to call an ajax function on the  onchange event of dropdown that gets data from database.

Answer (score 0):

ajax is your friend. Either you can use raw javascript or jquery( easier ). Your steps would be..
1. Write a php code block, most probably a function, which takes the selected application option from post, queries the database and outputs the result.
2. In your current page, write a js code that fires the ajax request each time user selects an option. This ajax will send the selected option to the php script by post method and u can grab the output upon the success of the request.

```
$('.selectBox').on('change', function(){
// do your ajax here.
});
```

something like that..

Comment: forgive me if the formatting of the code block is ugly..i am on a basic nokia phone..:p

Comment: Thanks Praveen. Can you please elaborate or cite an example?